# How do you set a rotating category color on incoming messages?

Tags: vba, outlook, categories

Our customer support team receives emails in a group inbox.  They would like to assign a category/color to each incoming email so they can better divvy up client requests.

As there are three people on the team, I created three categories with a unique associated color.  They want the color to rotate sequentially in a loop (i.e. Person1 gets mailItem1 category red, Person2 gets mailItem2 category orange, Person3 gets mailItem3 category yellow, Person1 gets mailItem4 category red, etc.)

I set up a rule to run on incoming messages and cobbled together a script from what I could find online regarding Outlook mailItem properties, but it isn't assigning a single color to inbox items.

```
Sub AssignUserColor(myMail As MailItem)
    Dim strID As String
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

    strID = myMail.EntryID
    Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
    'myMail.Category.Color = olCategoryColorBlue
    myMail.Categories = olCategoryColorBlue
    objMail.Save

    Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a MailItem (myMail) -- what happen if you use it directly instead of trying to fetch a new one? The OOM is a fickle beast -- don't try to get around its caching model. You may also want to see if you can't set something else, such as a subject, to see if the code runs to the parts expected and can perform an update.

In addition, the type of [Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb207135%28office.12%29.aspx) is a string but olCategoryColorBlue (from the OlCategoryColor enumeration) is a number. Hmm. Not sure how this works. I believe you must convert the enumeration value to the "name". See the links on [Categories Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424469.aspx), which can be indexed via an index (OlCategoryColor?) or linear-searched.

Also, I believe you can do this with just the Rules Wizard (no VBA) though.

Hope you find your problem. Happy coding.

Comment: Just thought I'd post a solution for anyone who's interested.  I kept experimenting and eventually got it to work.

Comment: Public Sub ReadAssignEmails(item as outlook.mailitem)

Answer (score 0):

I added a button to the toolbar that launches a userform that collects names of which employees are available to receive emails.  Those names - my categories are similarly named - and the total of employees, are public in scope.  These two procedures are called from the same main procedure that populates the user form.

```
Public sumOfAvailableEmps As Integer
Dim empArray(4) As String

Private Sub CheckAvailableUsers()

Dim x As Integer
Dim emp1 As Boolean, emp2 As Boolean, _
        emp3 As Boolean, emp4 As Boolean      'has emp already been
                                                    'added to array of available
                                                    'users?
'initialize whether emp has been counted yet
emp1 = False
emp2 = False
emp3 = False
emp4 = False

    For x = 0 To 3
        If UserForm1.emp1 = True And ajCount = False Then
            empArray(x) = "Emp1 Items"
            ajCount = True
        ElseIf UserForm1.emp2 = True And bsCount = False Then
            empArray(x) = "Emp2 Items"
            bsCount = True
        ElseIf UserForm1.emp3 = True And kwCount = False Then
            empArray(x) = "Emp3 Items"
            kwCount = True
        ElseIf UserForm1.emp4 = True And paCount = False Then
            empArray(x) = "Emp4 Items"
            paCount = True
        Else
            empArray(x) = ""
        End If
    Next x

End Sub

Private Sub AssignColorCategory()

Dim myOlNameSpace As NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim myItems As items
Dim itemCount As Long

Set myOlNameSpace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = myOlNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Set myItems = objFolder.items


itemCount = myItems.Count

    For Each item In myItems
        If TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
             Select Case itemCount Mod sumOfAvailableEmps
                 Case 0
                     item.Categories = empArray(0)
                 Case 1
                     item.Categories = empArray(1)
                 Case 2
                     item.Categories = empArray(2)
                 Case 3
                     item.Categories = empArray(3)
                 Case Else
                     item.Categories = empArray(0)
             End Select
             'without save method, the color change won't display on-screen
             item.Save
         End If
    Next


'release memory
Set myItems = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set myOlNameSpace = Nothing
```